# Activity being destroyed after startActivityForIntent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera-intent

I'm struggling with my application lately.
I have an activity 'MyActivity' with a textview holding the current date

**The use case is simple:**
- user clicks a button to start camera intent from MyActivity
- user takes picture
- MyActivity is resumed and the textview still holds the current date

This works fine on most devices. However, on devices with low memory, the activity is destroyed during camera intent and when I get back to MyActivity,
the textview no longer holds the date.

Using debugger and breakpoints, I could see the following:

```
05-16 12:41:35.364 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: onDestroy: MyActivity@10140ca0
05-16 12:41:35.414 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: onCreate: MyActivity@2e507264
05-16 12:41:35.804 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: setting textview date : "16 05 2018"
05-16 12:41:37.206 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: onDestroy: MyActivity@2e507264
05-16 12:41:37.236 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: onCreate: MyActivity@253f67dc
05-16 12:41:37.706 3614-3614/com.example.test D/TAG: setting textview date : "16 05 2018"
```

As you can see the textview is being set just as expected, but the screen doesn't show it.

If anyone can guess the solution to this annoying I would be thankful.

**Edit**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + this);
    // inflate the layout 
    loadContent(R.layout.activity_invoice_more_options);

    dateView = findViewById(R.id.date_view);        
    buttonView = findViewById(R.id.button_view);

    dateView.setText(Tools.getFormattedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), "dd MM yyyy"));

    // set button click listener
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseImageIntent = getPickImageIntent(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.choose_action));
            startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, FILE_PICKER_RESULT);
        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data == null) return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_PICKER_RESULT:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
            // retrieve file content and name
            final String fileName = Tools.getFileName(this, data);
            String fileContent = Tools.getFileContent(this, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post you're activity code. That part that works with textview.

Comment: Please share your code of onActivityResult.

Comment: I actually don't do much in the onActivityResult

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, but you can use `saveInstanceState` to preserve the date.

Comment: You do not call super.onCreate in the Activity, or you just skipped it here?

Comment: `super.onCreate` is called in another method I omitted to show here. My bad. Regarding `saveInstanceState`, even if it doesn't make sense, I tried using it but it didn't improve the behaviour